# Example for sending a mail manually in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a web app and i want to add compose mail function so that the users can send the mail to others. I have searched for it and found only the confirmation mail sending after registration but i want the user to login and then he should be able to send a mail. how can i do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use action mailer  to send mail,visit rails [guilde](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).It's simple if you know little bit of rails